# Java Slick2D Library

Tags: slick2d, java

I decided to play around with Slick2D and LWJGL library. LWJGL is running pretty much smoothly, except with Slick2D which is working too but I'm getting a bit confused of two things. First some error, which says when I run test for Slick2D "WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 7", here you can see a screenshot from the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Vvb.jpg and secondly (also Slick2D lib) I hear some noise inside my PC, which I haven't experienced before with applications nor now with LWJGL. Then I decided to open BuckyWorld 2D game, just to make sure it's not problem with that test project, but still I get the same error and same noise.

p.s. Check thise screenshots below if I have everything set up properly, I'm not sure jsut for sources, do I have to add something to it ?

Classpath: i.imgur.com/F0CZYEt.jpg

Sources: i.imgur.com/i3Uwjuw.jpg

Javadoc: i.imgur.com/VjlGIMg.jpg

Comment: I'd suggest you abandon Slick2D in favor for LIBGDX.  Kevin Glass, the creator of Slick2D has said before on his blog that LIBGDX has more features, and he is impressed by it.  I've been working with LIBGDX for a year or so.  Doc is sparse at times, but its performance is unmatched.

Comment: Thanks for reply William. Well, I have one year exp in Java and about half year in programming 2D games, without help from libraries. I've been planning for a long time to try this library, so I thought Slick2d would be a great one to start with, and then maybe jMonkey engine. However, thanks for that suggestion I appreciate it, I might decide to try it out.

Comment: I used GTGE first, then Slick2D.  Slick2D is great, but is lacking some of the nice things in LIBGDX.  Slick2D and LIBGDX are about as primitive as one another, but LIBGDX requires slightly less legwork imo.  Also LIBGDX can run on PC, app, linux Desktops, as an applet, on android, and iphone. Shoot me a PM if you try it out, I'll try and help.

Comment: I'll definitely try it out, but not this days becuase I'm going to have next week an exam from math. I'm actually watching a youtube channel http://www.youtube.com/user/badlogicgames/videos from one of the creators of that library. However, could you tell me for those three pictures that I've uploaded, did I forget to add some of the files in Library Sources?

Comment: Good luck with your exam! Set up looks ok to me.  It has been a while since I set up libgdx project though.